# Values of the blood tests pancreatic amylase and lipase

Tags: biochemistry

Anyone know what is considered slightly elevated, moderately elevated and strongly elevated values of pancreatic amylase and lipase?

Many different laboratories in my country divide between these categories for interpretation, but they don't specify which values qualify for each category.

Hope this is the right place for this kind of question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary a fixed value. I think it depends on the doctor that interprets it. For e.g if amylase's normal value is 70, and laboratoy value is 80, i would say it is slightly elevated. A value of 300 is strongly elevated.

Comment: The poster asks for a range that has some official or formal basis. What you consider normal etc. is of no relevance if it is not backed up by evidence that it is based on a scale that is in operation. Please read the Help on answering questions for this site.